# Add Argument to JS Promise

Tags: javascript, promise, tableau-api

How can I alter the code I have to accomplish to goal of referencing the original event (or properties/methods of it) in the subsequent code.

```
tViz.addEventListener(tableauSoftware.TableauEventName.MARKS_SELECTION, onMarksSelection);

function onMarksSelection(marksEvent) {
    return marksEvent.getMarksAsync().then(showMarksHelp);
}

function showMarksHelp(marks){
    I want to access a method from the marksEvent variable but here I can only access
    the marks variable from getMarksAsync(). I need it here because stuff will also be
    based on the marks variable contained here.
}
```

I feel like I could restructure my JS to accomplish this or pass something in somewhere, but after reading about Promises and the Tableau documentation I'm still lost. I don't want to use any global variables.

**EDIT**
So I changed my code to the below:

```
function onMarksSelection(marksEvent) {
    var marks = marksEvent.getMarksAsync().then(function(marks){
        showMarksHelp(marks,marksEvent)
    });
}

function showMarksHelp(marks,marksEvent){}
```

Is this a/the correct method to accomplish what I did? I just made it up but it seems like it works.

Comment: Why would you return a promise from an event handler at all?

Comment: It's Tableau's API. When someone interacts with it in the first line, I run my function to see what they interacted with and I do that via their methods which is the second function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an anonymous function, you can capture the value of `marksEvent` and then call `showMarksHelp` with two arguments.

```
function onMarksSelection(marksEvent) {
  return marksEvent.getMarksAsync().then(function(marks) {
    // marksEvent is accessible in here
    showMarksHelp(marksEvent, marks);
  });
}

function showMarksHelp(marksEvent, marks) {
  // content of showMarksHelp here
}
```

Comment: Glad I got someone to concur.